# Caliburn.Micro NotifyOfPropertyChange different way of UI Update

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Can somebody please explain to me why ItemsControl only updates my UI when i reactivate my view manually via  Caliburn.Micro Framework (Button x:Name="LoadView").

And why this way actually updates my UI immediately?

```
 Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>
        (await dataAccess.Starter(progress, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(true));
```

what am i understanding wrong?
Edit:

```
    private static BindableCollection<DataModel> _IDirectorys;
```

without the static it doesnt update at all.

```
    private static BindableCollection<DataModel> _IDirectorys;

    public BindableCollection<DataModel> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _IDirectorys;
        }
        set
        {
            _IDirectorys = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Data);
        }
    }


    public async Task StartScan()
    {
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

        _IDirectorys = new BindableCollection<DataModel>
            (await dataAccess.Starter(progress, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(true));
    }


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
```

Comment: It would appear that `BindableCollection` doesn't notify property changed on adds/deletes, using an `ObservableCollection<T>` might be the solution, it publishes collection changed events

Comment: just tried ObservableCollection<T>  and it doesnt update it at all. Though when i declare Data instead of _IDirectorys it updates immediately

Comment: EDIT: forgot the static, with it, it has the same effect as BindableCollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the backing field of a non-static property must not be static. Remove the `static` modifier from _IDirectorys.

Then when you create a new collection in StartScan, assign it to the property, not the backing field. Otherwise `NotifyOfPropertyChange` is not called.

```
public async Task StartScan()
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

    Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>(await dataAccess.Starter(progress, cts.Token));
}
```

Note that you neither need a BindableCollection nor an ObservableCollection when you only create new collection instances, but never add or remove elements to/from an existing collection.

So this should also work:

```
private IEnumerable<DataModel> data;

public IEnumerable<DataModel> Data
{
    get => data;
    set
    {
        data = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Data);
    }
}

public async Task StartScan()
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

    Data = await dataAccess.Starter(progress, cts.Token);
}
```

---

Last but not least, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. This is sufficient:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, i implemented it as you suggested i kept the BindableCollection though since i have to add/delete stuff in the future.My question is still unanswered. What is the reason behind the "not updating immediately?"

Comment: As explained, you had `_IDirectorys = new BindableCollection<DataModel>()` instead of `Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>()`. The former doesn't call of NotifyOfPropertyChange.

Comment: Got it, Thank you. Didnt know that it doesnt call the NotifyOfPropertyChange.

Comment: The NotifyOfPropertyChange call is in the property setter. If you don't set the property, it will obviously not be called.